# Can't avoid switch conditional using Strategy Pattern

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to use the strategy pattern to solve a design issue. It's a college system. There is an User, and the user can be either a Student, a Professor or an Administrator. So, I have an `User` entity like this

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Model\User;

class User
{
    private $user_type;

    public function __construct(UserType $user_type)
    {
        $this->user_type = $user_type;
    }

    public function hasAccess()
    {
        $this->type()->hasAccess();
    }
    // others methods 
}
```

The `UserType` is an Interface, that each user type implements it. Like the `StudentType`:

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Model\User;

class StudentType implements UserType
{
    public function hasAccess()
    {
        // checks if has access
    }
}
```

Notice that I don't want to create an ACL with `Strategy Pattern`, I'm already using one. The point here is that each type of user has a proper way to access an environment, so I have to do some checks.

So the question is the method `type()` of the `User` entity. I know that I don't have to think about database when modeling my entities, but all these types, users, students are stored in a relational database, and I can't avoid this. So, I'm using `Doctrine` for persistence.

When I retrieve an `User` from the database, Doctrine don't uses the constructor of my `User`, so the `$user_type` attribute will be only a number. Then, to guarantee that `$user_type` property will always be a class that implements the `UserType` interface, I had to use the `type()` method to do something like this

```
// method inside User class
public function type()
{
    if (!$this->user_type instanceof UserType) {
        switch ($this->user_type) {
            case 1:
                $this->user_type = new StudentType;
                break;
            // some others ugly conditions for each type
        }
   }
   return $this->user_type;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid using these conditionals? Or am I thinking in the wrong way about Strategy Pattern?

Comment: Maybe take a look at Doctrine's inheritance: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping . But I do suspect that a role based approach is probably all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook to `postLoad` event in Doctrine's `EventManager` see [this](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html). This event will let you process each entity after is has been loaded from the DB.

Personally I don't like using `EventManager` too much and I don't like entities being "too clever" either. I think an instance of `User` entity itself should not be able to decide if it has access somewhere or not. Some business object/service should be in charge of deciding that. This service would have `hasAccess` method that takes your `User` entity and answers appropriately. (Having logic of your `StudentType`, `TeacherType` etc.) Then the service would be able to handle `user_type` or role, no matter if it is an integer or string.